# how to enable "show on lock screen" permission programmatically on xiaomi mi phone

Tags: android, permissions, lockscreen, xiaomi

How can I enable "show on lock screen" permission on Xiaomi phones? Is it  possible by programmatically or add custom permission in manifest or still somehow? Is it possible to know whether this permission has already been granted or not?
[image]

Comment: That's a custom Xiaomi setting, and I don't think it's even a permission. It just shows that app's notifications on the lock screen.

Comment: I think there's a confusion regarding this permission. It actually doesn't control showing your app's notifications on the lock-screen, it controls whether you can show an activity on the lockscreen.

Comment: All SO Developers needs to ask Google - Make a Policy for Custom ROM modifiers i.e. Chinese ROM modifier companies ( 99% phones ) must adhere to maintain originality of android and can just modify UI Theme and not overall working

Comment: Same problem. Why don't the сhinese do normal documentation? Why should we as developers suffer?

Comment: for popular app like whatsapp this option is enabled by default :(